# How to run unit tests with kivy MeshLinePlot?

Tags: python, unit-testing, kivy

I have a class in an application that uses a `MeshLinePlot` from `kivy_garden.graph` to update a plot as data in the class changes. I wanted to write some tests, but I'm getting strange errors when using the stock `unittest` module and with `pytest`.

Here's the situation with my testing script:

```
# test_container.py
import unittest
from kivy_garden.graph import MeshLinePlot

class Container():
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
        #self.mesh = MeshLinePlot()

class TestOne(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_dummy(self):
        print('In dummy_test()')
        self.assertEqual(1, 1)

    def test_class_init(self):
        print('In test_class_init()')
        c = Container(1)
        self.assertEqual(c.id, 1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

If you run this code as is, both of the tests will fire and pass regardless of whether you use `unittest.main` or call it from `pytest`. However, if you uncomment the line where the mesh is instantiated in `Container`, we get different results. With `unittest.main()`, only `test_class_init()` prints anything and the test results are not shown:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\ganzk\.kivy\logs\kivy_20-07-26_90.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.2.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.2.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "c:\Users\ganzk\Desktop\peaks\kivy_env\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "c:\Users\ganzk\Desktop\peaks\kivy_env\Scripts\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
In test_class_init()
```

Now, if we try running the script with pytest (call: `pytest test_container.py`), we get no test results, no print statements, and the following long-ish backtrace: https://pastebin.com/98q7BaeN.

Information about my package installation: https://pastebin.com/YNMVx2wK.

I'm really stumped about how to get this working. Looking at the `init` for `MeshLinePlot`, it doesn't seem like it's doing much of anything, let alone preventing unit tests from proceeding. I haven't seen anyone with a similar problem on the internet; anyone know how I can get tests to run on a class that uses a `MeshLinePlot`? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone else finds this, here's the workaround I found. Test cases that instantiate kivy graphics instructions must inherit from `kivy.tests.common.GraphicUnitTest`. Otherwise, code that initializes kivy's canvas etc. will fail and kill your tests entirely.

The following script works as expected:

```
# test_container.py
import unittest
from kivy_garden.graph import MeshLinePlot
from kivy.tests.common import GraphicUnitTest

class Container():
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
        self.mesh = MeshLinePlot()

class TestOne(GraphicUnitTest):
    def test_dummy(self):
        print('In dummy_test()')
        self.assertEqual(1, 1)

    def test_class_init(self):
        print('In test_class_init()')
        c = Container(1)
        self.assertEqual(c.id, 1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```